# nil found when using SFSafariViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

In this view I am composing an URL with some variables and opening it through SFSafariVeiwController. I get this error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value".

The code used is the following:

```
@IBAction func pay(_ sender: Any) {

    let urlString:String = "https://website.com/video.php?user=\(user)&pass=\(pass)&texto=\(texto)&esp=\(espec)&l_origen=\(l_origen)&l_destino=\(l_destino)"


    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL)
        self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you for your time

EDIT with Amey's answer:

```
@IBAction func pay(_ sender: Any) {

        let urlString:String = "https://website/video.php?user=\(user)&pass=\(pass)&texto=\(texto)&esp=\(espec)&l_origen=\(l_origen)&l_destino=\(l_destino)"

        if let tempString = urlString {
            if let url = URL(string:tempString){
                let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
                self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I get "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" in "if let tempString = urlString {"

Comment: Does it work if ou change your urlString to something like "https://stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: No, not working and I got the following: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in AppDelegate

Comment: Try to write the full url of stackoverflow, with h t t p before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL)
```

you are force unwrapping an optional variable and you get nil so apps crash .

```
if let tempString = urlString {
 let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: tempString ) as URL)
}
```

This Will help To Prevent The Crash And YOu Have To Replace The code

This Code Works:-

```
 if let url = URL(string:urlString){
 let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please, see updated OP, I am getting an error with your code

Comment: There is no need for the `if let tempString` line since urlString isn’t optional. And this code does actually fix the problem of the invalid URL.

Comment: @SiensImac pls Check the Code Edited It It Should Work

Comment: @Amey Now it works if the variable "texto" is only one word... If it's more than one or it is one word plus an space, the button does not open the webpage...